# Annotations (bean validation) don´t work

Tags: java, jsf-2, annotations

I added some annotations (bean validation) as below, but they do not work.

```
@NotNull
@Min(value=3)
private double salario;

@NotNull
@Min(value=5)
@Max(value=19)

private Integer codigo; 
@NotNull
private Date aniversario;
```

I imported the libraries:

```
com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull import;
javax.validation.constraints.Max import;
javax.validation.constraints.Min import;
```

My fields are not being validated. What can it be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. you probably have the wrong import for `@NotNull` (it should be in the `javax.validation.constraints` package).  The other annotations don't matter if the values are `null`.  And since you have this annotation wrong, they would be allowed to be `null` except for the `double`, which by the way, the `@NotNull` is useless on, since `double` always has a value.
2. Are you sure you have a validation library included in your app?  I'm not sure whether jsf (whichever impl you're using) comes with one or not.

And at what point are you expecting validation to occur?  If this is a jsf managed bean, it will most likely be validated at the end of the set values phase.

If it's not JSF managed, you'll have to validate yourself most likely through the API.

Comment: Matt, I corrected the import, but still did not work. (import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;)

Comment: yes annotation from  javax.validation.constraints is to be used. I was of the   impression that it comes inbuilt but separate jar (or through build tool) file need to be added to the project.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Matt. The NotNull import is coming from wrong package. Change it to `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`. Moreover, this only works out of the box if JSr 303 implementation is there in the classpath. From [here](http://andyschwartz.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/whats-new-in-jsf-2/#validation)

In environments where a bean validation implementation is present, JSF automatically validates constraints for beans that are referenced by UIInput values.

In addition, `<f:validateBean>` may be used to fine tune bean validation behavior. For example, the validationGroups attribute may be used to manually specify which validation groups should be taken into account when validating a particular component:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.foo}">
  <f:validateBean validationGroups="com.foo.validation.groups.Billable"/>
</h:inputText>
```

When validation constraints fail, any associated error messages are automatically translated into FacesMessages by the JSF implementation, thus communicating the failures to the end user without placing any burden on the application developer.

**Empty Field Validation**

In previous JSF releases, Validators were not applied to EditableValueHolder components with null/empty submitted values. Unfortunately, this behavior limits the utility of constraints that actually check null/empty values, such as the JSR 303 `@NotNull` constraint. In order to support `@NotNull` and other similar constraints, JSF 2 changes the behavior of null/empty value validation. As of JSF 2, when a JSR-303 implementation is present, null/empty values are validated.

Since this may cause problems for legacy Validator implementations that do not expect to see null/empty values, the `javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS` context parameter can be used to disable this behavior.

Comment: Pangea Libraries changed and yet nothing happens, does not validate the null fields and not fields with the values ​​Min and Max. It is as if he hadn't the annotations.

Answer (score -1):

Try to uninstall the latest Android SDK Build-tool.
Go to Android SDK manager - > uninstall Android SDK Build-tool.